# How to stop an async task?

Tags: c#, task

Suppose that I have a `List<Task>` which help me to manage all the task based on index:

```
private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(new Task[3]);
```

When the application start a menu is displayed, and the user can select which task can start, simply:

```
public void Menu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1. Task");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Task");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Task");
    Console.WriteLine("0. Exit");

    ConsoleKeyInfo input;

    do
    {
        input = Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();

        switch (input.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                 StartTask(1);
                 break;
            case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                 StartTask(2);
                 break;
            case ConsoleKey.NumPad3:
                 StartTask(3);
                 break;
        }
     } while (input.Key != ConsoleKey.NumPad0);
}
```

inside the method `StartTask` I pass the number of `Task` to execute, this is the logic:

```
public void StartTask(int instance)
{
    int index = instance - 1;

    //Task not yet instantiated, create new one
    if(tasks.ElementAtOrDefault(index) == null)
    {
        //Make a new cancellation token
        cts.Insert(index, new CancellationTokenSource());

        tasks.Insert(index, new Task(async () => 
        {
            await foo.DoWork(cts[index].Token);
        }, cts[index].Token));

        if(!tasks[index].Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running))
        {
            tasks[index].Start();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see I also have a `List<CancellationTokenSource> cts` which help me to terminate the task. The `Cancel` method is placed in another menu like above.

Now the problem is pretty clear: I can't do that because the checking is executed before the `await` operation of `DoWork();` that contains this:

```
public class Foo
{
     private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
     {
         while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
             string newData = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

             Console.WriteLine(newData);
              await Task.Delay(200);
         }
     }
}
```

essentially: how can I stop the `Task` that execute the `loop` with the `CancellationToken`?

The token passed as parameter cannot change the value if the stop is executed later the start. Essentially the value of `IsCancellationRequested` is changing only in the `Task` class context, not in the argument passed.

Comment: You need to forward the token

Comment: @AluanHaddad what about if the `DoWorkAsync` is in another class? The variable change will not happen in the other class only in the Task context

Comment: If `StartTask` is not marked with `async`, how can you `await DoWorkAsync`?

Comment: @Fildor I don't need to await it, I simply need to start a task and manage the task by stopping it

Comment: I meant: You cannot use `await`. But it's in your example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass cancellation token to DoWorkAsync.
And use it in 'while' loop as a condition.

```
while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{ 
   await Task.Delay(200, token); 
}
```

'token' should be passed as a parameter.
To be honest, I think there is too much redundant code in your solution ...

How to cancel task using cancellation token source:

```
void CancelTask(int taskNumber)
{
   int index = taskNumber - 1;
   cts[index].Cancel();
}
```

This code will set 'IsCancellationRequested' flag of 'token' you use in the loop into 'true'.

Comment: How can I prevent redundancy? EDIT: I tried it, and it won't work. I get the `IsCancellationRequested` to true only in the class where I made the change, not in the method class. That's because the cancellation is made later of loop start

Comment: I see redundancy in 'StartTask' method. It is too complicated for just starting a task. Also, I don't understand how do you want to cancel the tasks you started. What method is responsible for that? Are you parsing user input? Or you want to do that automatically?

Comment: please check my update, you will see that in my case your solution not work

Comment: @Spartaok can you please explain how do you want to stop your tasks? Ideally tasks will stop by themselves when they will stop execution, in your case, if you have infinite loop, you need a way to manually call 'CancellationTokenSource.Cancel' method

Comment: essentially each task started by the user will run a scraper of a specific part of a web site, I want be able to manage the start and the stop of each task of the scraping process. The `Cancel` method, as I said in the question, is placed in another menu

Comment: Loop should not change the value of 'token.IsCancellationRequested' class during execution. You need additional code, to manually call 'Cancel' method of appropriate CancellationTokenSource in 'cts' array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182861/discussion-between-spartaok-and-eramir).